Allow comboboxes to be null
I have a form that gathers information to create a new client. Besides the client name, its possible many entries may be left blank. I have 5 combox boxes that initially have no values unless selected. Everything works fine if all the data is filled out but the comboboxes throw errors if nothing is selected and the save button is pushed.
ClientClass client = new ClientClass
{
    ClientName = txtClientName.Text,
    Address = txtAddress.Text,
    Address2 = txtAddress2.Text,
    City = cbxCity.Text,
    State = cbxState.Text,
    ZipCode = cbxZip.Text,
    Phone = txtPhone.Text,
    Fax = txtFax.Text,
    AccountManager = cbxAcctManager.Text,
    EmailDomain = txtEDomain.Text,
    EmailFormat = cbxEMFormat.SelectedValue.ToString(),                    
};

The error happens here and I understand why its happening, it's trying to get the selected value of the combo box to get the text but none has been selected. How do I allow for no selection?
I have tried putting in
    if (cbxCity.SelectedValue == null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Null");
        cbxCity.Text = "";
        cbxState.Text = "";
        cbxZip.Text = "";
        cbxEMFormat.Text = "";
        cbxAcctManager.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show(cbxCity.Text);
    }

above but when it gets to the class it still check the selected value.
I just want the save to go through even if no selection is made.
Thank you

What error do you get?

The following may be of interest: SelectedIndex: A zero-based index of the currently selected item. A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected. Also see SelectedValue: InvalidOperationException:  The assigned value is null or the empty string ("").

EmailFormat = cbxEMFormat.SelectedValue?.ToString(),

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue.get returned null.

dr.nulls suggestion worked but I do not see how to accept it as the answer.

You can AND SHOULD answer your own question and accept it, if you resolved it yourself. Often times, people will post a solution as a comment rather than an answer because they couldn't be bothered fleshing it out enough to be an acceptable answer. I've done it myself and I imagine that's what's happened here. In that case, you should flesh it out and provide a full answer. That will help you build your reputation as well as help others who may have similar problems. Don't leave resolved questions unanswered.

dr.nulls suggestion worked but I do not see how to accept it as the answer - it was a comment, not an answer. Comments cannot be accepted as answers because theyre supposed to be used for clarifying the question only. That said, many people, myself included, use them to make small suggestions of things you might want to look at or try to work towards a solution yourself without [the commenter] getting involved in writing out a full, in depth answer. As you have resolved your own problem youre free to post an answer and accept it

EmailFormat = cbxEMFormat.SelectedValue?.ToString(),


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
